# An intriguing question about classical probability

Tags: probability

It is a question about classical models of probability.

Assume two guys A and B play chess. The probability of A winning *ONE GAME* is **a** whilst B is **b** with $a + b = 1.$ (There is no draw)

Assume that A is a better player, $a > b$. And the rule is: if A wins three games in a row first, A wins; if B wins two games in a row first, B wins. And eventually one will win the game.

We can name the event of A winning as **E** and B winning as **F**. Now, if we want to calculate the probability of A winning, it must comprise a series of events such as *EF EEF EF EEF*. We may assume that A wins the first game, but my confusion starts here: we have no idea what will happen next, as EF and EEF are both legitimate choices throughout the process, and we don't know what will appear. For example, *EF EEE* is OK and *EEF EEF EEF EEE* also works.

(There are similar questions with some variations, but I don't really understand some of the answers)

Comment: When you say $A$ wins- is $a$ the probability of winning one game, or three games in a row?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta I edited. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: This can be mathematically modeled and solved for using a Markov chain. Do you know what a Markov chain is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be the probability of A winning the match (not game), and $Q$ be the probability of B winning. Then-
$$P+Q=1$$
Let us attempt to calculate $Q$. If we represent B winning a game with F, then, if B wins at the $r^{th}$ game, it is decided that the outcome of $(r-1)^{th}$ game is F and that of $(r-2)^{th}$ game is E. So, we have to create a word made of E and F of length $r-3$, with no sub-string 'FF' or 'EEE'.

If we focus on the F's, it is clear that the number of F's in the $r-3$ length string can be, a maximum of $\left\lceil \frac {r-3}{2} \right \rceil =k$, if $r\geq 6$.
Suppose we take $l$ number of F's, $2\leq l \leq k$.
If we go by the stars and bars approach, the gap between two subsequent F's can be either $1$ or $2$. Also, for $l$ F's, the number of gaps is $l-1$. Thus, the problem to be solved is:

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_{l-1}=(r-3)-l$$ where $1\leq x_i \leq 2$. Thus, we have to find the coefficient of $x^{r-l-3}$ in $(x+x^2)^{l-1}$. Using the binomial theorem, this coefficient is $\binom {l-1}{r-2l-2}$.
Thus, the number of ways that B can win at the $r^{th}$ game is:
$$S=\sum_{l=2}^k \binom {l-1}{r-2l-2}$$
Hence, the probability of B winning at the $r^{th}$ game is:
$$q=S\cdot a^{r-l-2}\cdot b^{l+2}$$
Hence, since $r\geq 2$, we have:
$$Q=\sum q=\left(\sum_{r=6}^{\infty} \sum_{l=2}^k \binom {l-1}{r-2l-2}\cdot a^{r-l-2} \cdot b^{l+2}\right)+b^2+ab^2+(ab^3+a^2b^2)+2a^2b^3+a^3b^3+a^4b^3$$
Hence, $P=1-Q$. Note that the $b^2$, $ab^2$, $ab^3+a^2b^2$ and $2a^2b^3$ terms represent probabilities of B winning if $r=2$, $r=3$, $r=4$ and $r=5$ respectively, $a^3b^3$ represents  the $l=1$ case for $r=6$ and $a^4b^3$ represents the $l=1$ case for $r=7$. From $r=8$ onwards, the $l=1$ case is impossible anyway.

**Note:**
In particular, I put $a=b=\frac 12$ and evaluated the summation using Python code upto 2000 terms, it is approximately equal to $0.0375$. Hence, for that case $Q=0.5859+0.0375=0.6234$, which seems reasonable to me, since B only needs to win $2$ consecutive games to win.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we know for a fact that the match ends after $n$ games.  Then, assuming $n>2$, then game $n-3$ was won by $A$ and the last two games were either $EE$ or $FF$, which have respective probabilities of of $a^2$ and $b^2$.  (If $n=2$, then $B$ is guaranteed to win the match).  This means that given that the match ended after $n$ games, where $n>2$, the probability that $A$ won the match is $\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}$ and that $B$ won the match is $\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}$.

Let $p_n$ be the probability of the match ending after $n$ games.  Then, we have that the probability of $A$ winning the tournament is $\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}\sum_{n=3}^\infty p_n$ and of $B$ winning the tournament of $p_2+\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}\sum_{n=3}^\infty p_n$.

Because we are given that the match is guaranteed to end with one player winning, if we add these two together we should get a total of $1$.  Let's substitute $p_2=b^2$ and $k=\sum_{n=3}^\infty p_n$.  Then:
$$\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}k+b^2+\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}k=1$$
$$b^2+k=1$$
$$k=1-b^2$$

We then have that the probability of $A$ winning the match is:
$$\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}k=\frac{a^2-a^2b^2}{a^2+b^2}$$
and of $B$ winning the match is:
$$b^2+\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}k=\frac{a^2b^2+b^4+b^2-b^4}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{(a^2+1)b^2}{a^2+b^2}$$.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: ENRICHED ON REVISIT TO GIVE FULL ALGEBRAIC SOLUTION**

On revisiting this page, I realized that I could give a full algebraic answer instead of just computing for even odds, so have updated my answer

---

Since *consecutive* steps are needed for a win by either player, we can't model it as a random walk, but it can easily be handled by using *first step analysis*

[ I have taken probability of $A$ winning a **game**  to be **p** rather than **a**]

There are $6$ possible states for the game

- starting state $s$
- $A$ having won $1,2,$ or $3$ consecutive times,  $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$
- $B$ having won $1$ or $2$ consecutive times $(y_1,y_2)$

We need to trace the possibilities that can occur from each state along with their respective probabilities, e.g. from the starting state we can go to $x_1$ with probability $p$ or to $y_1$ with probability $(1-p)$

Proceeding thus, for P(A *ultimately* wins from $s$), we get the following equations

*For abbreviating notation, $s,\,x_1$ etc in the equations are used to represent the* **probabilities** *of eventually reaching the goal from the respective states*

$\displaylines{s = p\cdot x_1 +(1-p)\cdot y_1\;\;... [I]\\x_1=p\cdot x_2+(1-p)\cdot y_1\;\;...[II]\\x_2= p\cdot 1 +(1-p)\cdot y_1\;\;...[III]\\y_1= p\cdot x_1 + (1-p)\cdot 0\;\;...[IV]}$

To explain equations $[III]$ and $[IV], p\cdot 1$ as $A$ has reached goal, and similarly, $(1-p)\cdot 0$ because $B$ can't (when we are computing for $A$ winning the match)
[In the above equations, if we just exchange the $1$ and $0$ multipliers in the equations, we can get P(B wins), but of course, it is unnecessary, as P(A wins) + P(B wins) $= 1$]

*Note that anytime A's streak is broken, $A$ returns to $y_1$ and can win eventually only with a streak of three consecutive wins.*

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+for+s%3A+s%3Dp*X1%2B%281-p%29Y1%2C+X1%3Dp*X2%2B%281-p%29Y1%2C+X2%3D+p*1%2B%281-p%29Y1%2C+Y1%3Dp*X1%2B%281-p%29*0%2C%7B0%3C%3Dp%3C%3D1%7D) gives P(A wins) $= \dfrac{(2-p)p^3}{p^3-p+1}$

The answer I get with $p=0.5$, is P(A wins) = $0.3$, P(B wins) $= 0.7$ which tallies with neither of the previous answers, so both the previous answers seem to be erroneous.

Comment: @Dinoman: On revisiting, I realized that I could give the full formula, so please have a look at it. The approach I have adopted is based on the Markov property, which is a well known way of solving such problems.