# Does $\sum_{r=6}^\infty\frac{\sum_{l=2}^k\binom{l-1}{r-2l-2}}{2^r}$, where $k=\left\lceil\frac{r-3}2\right\rceil$, converge to $\frac3{80}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

In my attempt to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4208919/925091) MSE post, I came across the double summation:
$$\sum_{r=6}^{\infty} \frac {\sum_{l=2}^{k} \binom {l-1}{r-2l-2}}{2^r}$$
where $k=\left \lceil \frac {r-3}{2} \right \rceil$. This is what happens when we take $a=b=\frac 12$ for the original expression. I used Python to evaluate this upto 2000 terms, and the value came out to be suspiciously close to $\frac {3}{80}$.

Hence, I suspect it converges to $\frac {3}{80}$, but am unable to prove (or disprove) the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Python code:

```
import math
p=0
for r in range (6,2000):
    k=math.ceil((r-3)/2)
    s=0
    for i in range(2, k+1):
        if i-1>= r-i*2-2:
            s+=math.comb(i-1, r-i*2-2)
    p+=(s/2**r)
print(p)
```

This yields $p=0.03749999999999$ on my machine.

**PS:** Although I'm content with receiving an answer to the posted problem, methods which could be generalized for $0<a<1$ would be more helpful.